# building allegro5 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-12.04, allegro5

I'm trying to install allegro5 on ubuntu 12.04, and i'm following this tutorial: http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Ubuntu_and_Allegro_5 at first I couldn't find where allegro5 was installed, i ran find, and it turned out allegro5 was in /usr/local/allegro5/. So i proceeded to step 'build allegro'.

and that's where problem occurred, "cmake .. " gives me this error:

> CMake Error: The source directory "/usr/local/include/allegro5" does
>   not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt. Specify --help for usage, or
>   press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cmake's source directory should be the root folder containing the Allegro source. So you should be running `cmake ..` from your build folder (which is in the Allegro folder).

Check out this tutorial too if you're still having trouble. http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_SVN/Linux/Debian I just used it to install Allegro on Ubuntu 13.04 and it worked nicely.

P.S. I think that on Ubuntu /usr/local/lib is not in the search path for libraries, so you may get an error when you first try to run a compiled program. You can add it by putting the line `include /usr/local/lib` to the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` and then running `sudo ldconfig` to update the path.